# How do you perform an expected maximisation algorithm for a mixture model where the distributions are not Gaussian?

Tags: r

I am trying to adapt some code and perform an expected maximisation (EM) where the distributions are not normal. I can't seem to make it work so any help would be much much appreciated. I am trying to fit two generalised logistic distributions (GLM) rather than two normal. The first line is any dataset you may have. The next few lines after this is a k-means algorithm to find parameters that I can use to initialize with. The for loop is where I perform EM. I know that the code is clumsy in areas. I just want to make it work before I tidy it up. For example instead of a for loop I would like a while loop to tell me when we have reached a log-likelihood value that is small. If you have any questions, please do contact me.

```
x<-log10(y) # data here can be anything you like.


mem <- kmeans(x,2)$cluster
mu1 <- mean(x[mem==1])
mu2 <- mean(x[mem==2])
sigma1 <- sd(x[mem==1])
sigma2 <- sd(x[mem==2])
pi1 <- sum(mem==1)/length(mem)
pi2 <- sum(mem==2)/length(mem)

pete<-glogisfit((com_data[mem==1]))
bob<-glogisfit((com_data[mem==2]))
A.1<-as.vector(pete$parameters[1])
B.1<-as.vector(pete$parameters[2])
C.1<-as.vector(pete$parameters[3])

A.2<-as.vector(bob$parameters[1])
B.2<-as.vector(bob$parameters[2])
C.2<-as.vector(bob$parameters[3])


comp1<-com_data[mem==1]
comp2<-com_data[mem==2]

sum.finite <- function(x) {
sum(x[is.finite(x)])
}
Q <- 0
Q[2] <- sum.finite(log(pi1)+pete$loglik) + sum.finite(log(pi2)+ bob$loglik)

k <- 2

for(i in 1:10){
# E step
comp1 <- pi1 * dglogis(x, A.1, B.1, C.1)
comp2 <- pi2 * dglogis(x, A.2, B.2, C.2)
comp.sum <- comp1 + comp2

p1 <- comp1/comp.sum
p2 <- comp2/comp.sum

# M step

pi1 <- sum.finite(p1) / length(x)
pi2 <- sum.finite(p2) / length(x)

mu1 <- sum.finite(p1 * x) / sum.finite(p1)
mu2 <- sum.finite(p2 * x) / sum.finite(p2)

sigma1 <- sqrt(sum.finite(p1 * (x-mu1)^2) / sum.finite(p1))
sigma2 <- sqrt(sum.finite(p2 * (x-mu2)^2) / sum.finite(p2))


##################################
new.A <-x*p1
new.B <-x*p2

new.log.fit.A<-glogisfit(new.A)
new.log.fit.B<-glogisfit(new.B)

A.1<-as.vector(new.log.fit.A$parameters[1])
B.1<-as.vector(new.log.fit.A$parameters[2])
C.1<-as.vector(new.log.fit.A$parameters[3])

A.2<-as.vector(new.log.fit.B$parameters[1])
B.2<-as.vector(new.log.fit.B$parameters[2])
C.2<-as.vector(new.log.fit.B$parameters[3])
###################################

p1 <- pi1 
p2 <- pi2

k <- k + 1
Q[k] <- sum(log(comp.sum))
#print(c(A.1, B.1, C.1, A.2, B.2, C.2))
print(c(new.log.fit.A$loglik, new.log.fit.B$loglik))
}


hist(x, freq=FALSE, breaks=20)
curve(dglogis(x, A.1, B.1, C.1 ), add = TRUE, col = "black", lwd = 2)
curve(dglogis(x, A.2, B.2, C.2 ), add = TRUE, col = "black", lwd = 2)
```